# WAMP not updating changes in my files

Tags: web, localhost, wamp

So I am a novice at Web development and I am trying to create a website and am using WAMP to test out my PHP code and such. The issue I'm running into is that when I change my file, and try to refresh my localhost page on my browser, it gives me a file not found error. When I close out the localhost page and reopen it, the page that I changed appears properly and is updated properly.

I was just wondering whether there is an issue with my WAMP or whether having to open a new localhost page is necessary every time a file is updated?

Answer (score 0):

I would ensure the file path is correct, double check that you are dev-ing from the same folder that you are viewing in localhost. Also what worked for me is doing a browser cache refresh which is different from a simple refresh. http://refreshyourcache.com/en/cache/

Windows: ctrl + F5
Mac/Apple: Apple + R or command + R
Linux: F5

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/CI-social-media/css/registration_form.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
<script language="javascript" src="http://localhost/CI-social-media/js/registration_form.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/CI-social-media/css/registration_form.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
<script language="javascript" src="http://localhost/CI-social-media/js/registration_form.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

use this & solved problem

just add     `?v=<?php echo time(); ?>`     after `href="('path/url')` then after `"`

just add `?v=<?php echo time(); ?>`     after `src="('path/url')` then after  `"`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/CI-social-media/css/registration_form.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
        
<script language="javascript" src="http://localhost/CI-social-media/js/registration_form.js?v=<?php echo time(); ?>"></script>
```

Comment: I took a stab at formatting your answer so that all the code shows up, but it looks like there still may be some duplication in it.  Please [edit] it to further improve the formatting.